# How to extract the specific numbers or text using regex in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I have written the code to extract the numbers and the company name from the extracted pdf file.

sample pdf content:

```
#88876 - Sample1, GTRHEUSKYTH, -99WED,-0098B
#99945 - SAMPLE2, DJWHVDFWHEF, -8876D,-3445G
```

The above example is what my pdf file contains. I wanted to extract the App number which is after # (i.e) five numbers(88876) and App name which is after the (-) (i.e) Sample1. An write that to an excel file as separate columns which is App_number and App_name.

Please refer the below code which I have tried.

```
import PyPDF2, re
import csv
for k in range(1,100):
    pdfObj = open(r"C:\\Users\merge.pdf",'rb')
    object = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("C:\\Users\merge.pdf")
    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfObj)
    NumPages = object.getNumPages()
    pdfReader.numPages

    for i in range(0, NumPages):
        pdfPageObj = pdfReader.getPage(i)
        text = pdfPageObj.extractText()
        x=re.findall('(?<=#).[0-9]+', text)
        y=re.findall("(?<=\- )(.*?)(?=,)", text)
        print(x)
        print(y) 

    with open("out.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(x)
```

Please pour some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
text = '#88876 - Sample1, GTRHEUSKYTH'


App_number = re.search('(?<=#).[0-9]+', text).group()
App_name = re.search("(?<=\- )(.*?)(?=,)", text).group()
```

In the first regex you get the first consecutive digits after `#`, in the second one you get everything between `-`  and `,`

Hope it helped

Comment: App_number works fine but App_name fetches all the occurences which has everything between - and , . But i need the app_name which comes only after the app name ,should not fetch the occurrence after that. I have edited my sample input please refer to that.

Comment: And i have used 'find_all' instead of 'search' to fetch all the matches in the pdf file

Comment: I think I didn't understand your first comment

Comment: App_name works like - It fetches all the occurrences of characters between - and , in my pdf file . My requirement is to get only the occurrence after the #88876 . (i.e) Sample1, which I have given in the sample pdf content. Hope this explains

Comment: If you see the sample pdf content which I have mentioned, your code fetches 'Sample1' and as well as '99WED' . We need only Sample1, SAMPLE2 and so on...

Comment: Are you sure? Using your strings I keep getting 'Sample1' and 'SAMPLE2'

Comment: I have edited my code please take a look. According to that, it is printing all the occurrences of the - and , .